# How can I calculate $\left[{n\atop k}\right]$?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

$\left[\begin{array}{c}4\\2\end{array}\right]=11;\left[\begin{array}{c}7\\3\end{array}\right]=1624;$ and $\left[\begin{array}{c}7\\2\end{array}\right]=-1764$

How can I calculate $\left[\begin{array}{c}15\\6\end{array}\right]=?$ or $\left[\begin{array}{c}37\\11\end{array}\right]=?$

What a formula hidden behind these brackets? $\left[\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right]$

Comment: Unsigned stirling numbers of the first kind count a number of things.  If it is a small example, the value $\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}$ can be found as the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $x(x+1)(x+2)\dots(x+n-1)$.  For example, $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x$ so $\begin{bmatrix}4\\2\end{bmatrix}=11$.  You may also prefer to build it recursively as $\begin{bmatrix}n+1\\ k\end{bmatrix} =n\begin{bmatrix}n \\k\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}n \\k-1\end{bmatrix}$ using $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}=1$ and any other with a zero as either entry is equal to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That notation usually refers to the [*unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), but your ${7\brack 2}=-1764$ indicates that someone is using it for the signed Stirling numbers of the first kind.

The easiest way to compute them is by using the recurrence

$${{n+1}\brack k}=n{n\brack k}+{n\brack{k-1}}$$

for the unsigned numbers, with initial conditions ${0\brack 0}=1$ and ${n\brack 0}={0\brack n}=0$ for $n>0$. The signed version of ${n\brack k}$ is obtained by multiplying the unsigned version by $(-1)^{n-k}$. There is no nice closed form.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example?, what's the recursive algorithm?

Comment: @Dario: The algorithm is implicit in the recurrence: once you have ${n\brack k}$ and ${n\brack{k-1}}$, you can get ${{n+1}\brack k}$. For example, you have ${7\brack 3}=1624$ and ${7\brack 2}=1764$ for the unsigned numbers, so $${8\brack 3}=7{7\brack 3}+{7\brack 2}=7\cdot1624+1764=13132\;.$$ The signed version is $-13132$, since $8-3=5$ is odd. Basically you just build as much of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Table_of_values_for_small_n_and_k) as you need.